# What are the meanings of "Kangaroo", "Guillotine", and "Fox" in the UK House of Commons?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitution, parliament, terminology

What are these concepts in UK House of Commons? Are they some kind of MPs or are they names given to some roles while debating? What exactly are they?

1. The Kangaroo
2. The Guillotine
3. The Fox

Comment: Could you provide some context? For example: where did you hear about these terms? From searching on the internet, what do you think they mean?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff from the internet I got they are something related to UK's politics. The answer below makes it clear. However I still don't have any clue about `The Fox`

Answer (score 8):

The kangaroo is a practice which allows the Speaker to select which amendments to a Bill are to be debated<sup>1</sup>.

The guillotine is a common name for allocation of time motions<sup>2</sup>.

I'm afraid I have no clue what "the fox" might refer to.

<sub><sup>1</sup> http://www.leeds.ac.uk/law/teaching/law6cw/hc-3.htm

<sup>2</sup> http://www.parliament.uk/site-information/glossary/allocation-of-time-motion/</sub>

Comment: Also, the term "guillotine" is commonly used by MPs, whereas the term "kangaroo" is not.

Comment: So the question is now: What does the fox do?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it says "Gering ding ding ding dingeringeding!"

Answer (score 0):

"The Fox" as far as I'm aware refers to Charles James Fox, a famous 18th Century Whig party leader, the leader of the 'Foxite' faction within the Whigs, and the first person to hold the - at that point unofficial - role of Leader of the Opposition.

He was an extraordinarily colourful character. He began his career as a rather conservative politician, but he was moulded over time to become rather radically liberal. He was an opponent of the Government's actions in the American War of Independence, and supported the French revolution.

In the press, he was often depicted with vulpine characteristics - see the cartoon below depicting Fox on the left, and Lord Lincoln on the right.

[image: Charles James Fox standing on the left and Lord Lincoln on the right, facing each other as candidates in the Westminster elections.]

Quite recently, he was compared to Boris Johnson in a [letter to the Telegraph](https://www.alistairlexden.org.uk/news/whig-and-tory-lotharios-charles-james-fox-and-boris-johnson) by Lord Lexden.